# Проблемы со Scanner - выдает ошибку

Tags: java, scanner

Надо сохранить строку в файл. Вот тот способ, которым я записываю в файл:

```
if (sc==6){
    System.out.println("Введите новую книгу:");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Lib.txt")))){
        out.println(console);
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Но я не могу даже записать что либо, он автоматически сохраняет в файл какое то не понятное сообщение-

```
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\ ][decimal separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы в стрим укладываете **объект**, а не данные из него:

```
if (sc == 6) {
    System.out.println("Введите новую книгу:");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Lib.txt")))) {
        out.println(console.next());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

обратите внимание на строку: `out.println(console.next());`
вызов метода `.next()` возвращает строковое представление входящего потока с учетом разделителя. Дополню что стоит пользоваться методом `hasNext()` которым стоит проверить наличие остаточных данных (Как пример в вашем случае при вводу строки типа: ***"first \r\n second \r\n third \r\n"***  в файл log будут вписанно только **first** )

Answer (score 2):

В файл он записывает именно то, что вы ему передали - объект сканера. Стоит сначала сканером считать ввод, а уже его выводить в файл:

```
String str = console.nextLine()
...
out.println(str);
```

Кроме того, вы уверены, что сканер вам вообще нужен? Может вам хватит консоли?

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Console;

public class ConsoleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        Console console = System.console();
        String s = console.readLine();

        try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Lib.txt")))) {
            out.println(s);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }        
    }
}
```