# Scanner не работает, выдает ошибку

Tags: java, scanner

сканер выдает ошибку:

```
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\x{a0}][decimal separator=\x{2c}][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Qне число\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]
```

Сам код:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = sc.toString();
            System.out.print(s);
    
        }
```

среда разработки Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь объект класса `Scanner` перевести в `String`. Чтоб вывести в консоль введенную информацию можно написать так:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print(s);
    
        }
```

Вот похожий на вашу проблему [пост](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522589/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE-scanner-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83), в комментариях все указано более подробно
[Вот отличный сайт](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/klass-scanner), на котором все понятно и подробно написано о том, как работать со сканером, приведены все необходимые для работы методы